# Android unit test is fragment nullpointexception

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-fragments

When the `PersonListActivity` trigger, `BaseFragmentActivity` is working and I'm doing those process within `BaseFragmentActivity` in order of `onCreate` -> `doCreate` -> `initFragment`. When calls `fragment = createFragment();` inside of `initFragment`,  same time `createFragment()` function is working which is inside of `PersonListActivity` and then invoke the `PersonListFragment`..

The question is when I'm doing this with Unit Test enviroment (com.hpolat.example.personapp.`test`. ...), `PersonListFragment` keeps always response as `nullpoinexception`.  And I've noticed `PersonListFragment` is null during debugging. How I'll prevent to `PersonListFragment` not response null.

Thanks for advice!

**App Code;**

```
PersonListActivity.class

    public class PersonListActivity
            extends BaseFragmentActivity
    {
        @Override
        public Fragment createFragment() {
            return PersonListFragment.newInstance();
        }
    }
```

**BaseFragmentActivity.class**

```
public abstract class BaseFragmentActivity
        extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static final String FRG_ACTIVITY = "ActivityFragmentName";
    private Fragment mFragment;

    protected abstract Fragment createFragment();

    @LayoutRes
    protected int getLayoutResId() {
        return R.layout.layout_fragment_container;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.doCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }

    protected void doCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(getLayoutResId());
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            this.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        }

        setExtraLayoutItems();

        initFragment();
    }

    public void initFragment() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(getFragmentContainerId());

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = createFragment();

            if (fragment != null) {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                               .add(getFragmentContainerId(), fragment)
                               .commit();
            }
        }
        mFragment = fragment;
    }
```

**PersonListFragment.class**

```
public class PersonListFragment
        extends BaseListFragment
{
    public static final int LOADER_PERSON_ID = 2;

    public PersonListFragment() {
        //nop
    }

    public static PersonListFragment newInstance() {
        return new PersonListFragment();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Integer getListLoaderId() {
        return LOADER_PERSON_ID_ID;
    }
```

**Unit Test Code Block;**

```
public class PersonListFragmentTest{

    @Mock
    private PersonListFragment mPersonListFragment;
    private PersonListActivity mPersonListActivity;

    @Mock
    private BaseFragmentActivity mBaseFragmentActivity;


    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        mPersonListActivity = new PersonListActivity();
        mPersonListFragment = new PersonListFragment();

        mBaseFragmentActivity = new BaseFragmentActivity() {
            @Override
            protected Fragment createFragment() {
                return PersonListFragment.newInstance();
            }
        };

        mBaseFragmentActivity.initFragment(); //PersonListFragment is null

    }

    @Test
    public void getListLoaderIdTest_True() {
        assertEquals(1, 1); // for setup

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. The fragment was not working because I was working in the test folder. When I re-wrote the test in the androidTest folder, I got the right result without error.

(com.hpolat.example.personapp.`androidTest`. ...),